# Google big query or Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a 2 years of hands on experience on Apache hadoop, Hive and Hbase. Now I got an opportunity to work in Google Bigquery.

I'm confused to step into Bigquery. Can someone suggest what I should go for and why?

Comment: Are you asking what the key differences are with BigQuery? Or are you asking how to experiment with it and what makes a good testbed for it?

Comment: Two different beasts altogether. See Mikhail's answer/links. You should also  look at Dataproc & Dataflow/Beam if you are looking for more of a comparison to Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery Home: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/

Quickstarts: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts

How-to Guides: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/how-to